# How to find the increasing values in a dict?

Tags: python

After selected and put data into a dict from the census data on population, I have:

```
data = {'1991': {'0-to-14-percent': 20.85, 'year': '1991', '0-to-14 count': 5692555.0, '65-and-over-count': 3169970.0, '65-and-over-percent': 11.61, '15-to-64-count': 18434335.0, 'total-count': 27296860.0, '15-to-64-percent': 67.53}, '1981': {'0-to-14-percent': 22.52, 'year': '1981', '0-to-14 count': 5481100.0, '65-and-over-count': 2360975.0, '65-and-over-percent': 9.7, '15-to-64-count': 16501100.0, 'total-count': 24343175.0, '15-to-64-percent': 67.79}, '1941': {'0-to-14-percent': 27.8, 'year': '1941', '0-to-14 count': 3198551.0, '65-and-over-count': 767815.0, '65-and-over-percent': 6.67, '15-to-64-count': 7540289.0, 'total-count': 11506655.0, '15-to-64-percent': 65.53}, ('1941', {'0-to-14-percent': 27.8, 'year': '1941', '0-to-14 count': 3198551.0, '65-and-over-count': 767815.0, '65-and-over-percent': 6.67, '15-to-64-count': 7540289.0, 'total-count': 11506655.0, '15-to-64-percent': 65.53})
```

I'm trying to get the year in order, then check if the % are always increasing over those years (return Yes if it is increasing). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary is not structured correctly, however, I implemented the correct dictionary below and provided a solution.

```
data = {'1991': {'0-to-14-percent': 20.85, 'year': '1991', '0-to-14 count': 5692555.0, '65-and-over-count': 3169970.0, '65-and-over-percent': 11.61, '15-to-64-count': 18434335.0, 'total-count': 27296860.0, '15-to-64-percent': 67.53}, '1981': {'0-to-14-percent': 22.52, 'year': '1981', '0-to-14 count': 5481100.0, '65-and-over-count': 2360975.0, '65-and-over-percent': 9.7, '15-to-64-count': 16501100.0, 'total-count': 24343175.0, '15-to-64-percent': 67.79}, '1941': {'0-to-14-percent': 27.8, 'year': '1941', '0-to-14 count': 3198551.0, '65-and-over-count': 767815.0, '65-and-over-percent': 6.67, '15-to-64-count': 7540289.0, 'total-count': 11506655.0, '15-to-64-percent': 65.53}, '1941':{'0-to-14-percent': 27.8, 'year': '1941', '0-to-14 count': 3198551.0, '65-and-over-count': 767815.0, '65-and-over-percent': 6.67, '15-to-64-count': 7540289.0, 'total-count': 11506655.0, '15-to-64-percent': 65.53}}
final_data = {a:b['65-and-over-percent'] for a, b in data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'1991': 11.61, '1941': 6.67, '1981': 9.7}
```

If you just want a list:

```
final_data = [b['65-and-over-percent'] for a, b in data.items()]
```

Output:

```
[11.61, 6.67, 9.7]
```

Comment: thanks, sorry my question wasn't right so I just edited it. I was looking for %